# Findd command in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

In this [**link**](http://derekwyatt.org/2013/12/31/coding-scala-with-vim.html), I saw a guy using **findd** command. But, it seems Ubuntu doesn't have this command by default.

Are there any similar alternatives or how I could get it installed (recommend the best way) ?

**Update:**

In that video it's mentioned on 01:49 sec. It seems, what this command does is list all files including all files in sub-folders in one list.

Comment: are you sure there is findd command ?

Comment: On that video it's mentioned on 01:49 sec. It seems, what this command does is list all files including all sub-folders in one list.

Comment: find or findd double d

Comment: I believe it is an alias for `ls -R`

Answer (score 4):

This is an alias for `find .` I think it is some abbreviation of "find directory" or "find details" To make one for yourself use the following in terminal,

```
echo -e "\nalias findd='find .'">>~/.bash_aliases
```

And source your `~/.bash_aliases` as

```
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

If you do not have `~/.bash_aliases` replace all `~/.bash_aliases` above with `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

**findd** is a Linux/UNIX command line tool which can be used to find duplicate files. The way how files are compared and considered as duplicates is configurable, e.g. compare of content, size, name etc.

If the content of the file was chosen for compare (default), the program uses the MD5 sum to check if files are equal to each other. Before calculating the complete MD5 sum of a file it first checks if the size of the file and the MD5 sum of the first 8kB.<sup>[findd](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/findd/)</sup>

Example, to finds and reports all duplicate files in the '.'-Directory excluding zero sized files. The content of the files is compared, you would

```
findd -i . --recursive --no-zero-files
```

And I think it stands for Find Duplicate.

Comment: `findd`, according to this has a compulsory argument as the path. The video the OP has shown doesn't have one.